# Profile Picture and User Data in Single Graph API Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to write a single Graph API request that returns a large thumbnail of the user's profile picture, as well as their username/user ID.

I'm able to get the picture, name, and user ID with:

```
GET /v2.0/me?fields=id,name,picture
```

However, I can't figure out how to get a bigger version of the picture, like when I do this:

```
GET /v2.0/me/picture?type=large&redirect=false
```

I'm new to the Graph API and feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't figure it out. My initial thought was this, but I think it's applying the `type` and `redirect` options to the `me` node:

```
GET /v2.0/me?fields=id,name,picture&type=large&redirect=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your final goal is but would this help...?
Make the one call to simply retrieve the users ID and in your app you can then just use (by constructing the string) `http://graph.facebook.com/[facebookId]/picture?type=large` to access/view the large version of the profile picture.

Or

`GET /me?fields=id,first_name,picture.type(square).width(200).height(200)` where you decide what you want type, width and height to be.

Comment: Ah that seconds one was what I was looking for. I guess I just wasn't sure how to specify the size of the image; thanks!